# Delete only a Value from Ruby Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
myhash = {
  "csv-collector" => {
    "destination-queues" => ["csv-parser-queue"]
  },
  "csv-parser" => {
    "source-queue" => "csv-parser-queue",
    "destination-queues" => ["mtf-asn-lookup-expert-queue"]
  }
}
```

And I would like to delete the value `mtf-asn-lookup-expert-queue` leaving the hash like this:

```
myhash = {
  "csv-collector" => {
    "destination-queues" => ["csv-parser-queue"]
  },
  "csv-parser" => {
    "source-queue" => "csv-parser-queue",
    "destination-queues"=>[]
  }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
tag = "mtf"

myhash.each_pair do |key, value|
  value.delete_if { |inner_key, inner_value| inner_value[0].match(tag) }
end
```

Which gives me this output:

```
{
  "csv-collector" => {
    "destination-queues" => ["csv-parser-queue"]
  },
  "csv-parser" => {
    "source-queue" => "csv-parser-queue"
  }
}
```

It deletes the key and the value and I only want to delete the value. Can you guys help me out? :)

Thank you!! :D

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Do you want to remove any value containing `"mtf"` from all `destination-queue` arrays?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do!! @Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `value` refers to an inner hash, so `value.delete_if` attempts to remove a key-value pair from it.

To remove any value containing `"mtf"` from all `destination-queues` arrays, you could use:

```
tag = 'mtf'
myhash.each_value do |inner_hash|
  inner_hash['destination-queues'].delete_if { |element| element.include? tag }
end
```

The code assumes that every inner hash contains a `destination-queues` array.

Comment: Thank you very much :D @Stefan

Answer (score 0):

```
myhash.each {|_,g| g.each {|_,v| v.replace([]) if Array===v && v.first.match('mtf')}}
  #=> {"csv-collector"=>{"destination-queues"=>["csv-parser-queue"]},
  #    "csv-parser"=>{"source-queue"=>"csv-parser-queue", "destination-queues"=>[]}}
```